# Back Navigation Issue (Nav Graph) Issue (android)

Tags: android, xml, navigation, android-actionbar, navgraph

I am stuck in this issue of back navigation button for long while, I have tried different methods but still the problem is not resolved

Here is the IMAGE

[image]

**This is my issue**

- So, I have a home screen where i am signing up and login the user
- If the user is already logged in I have set nav graph to go to the dashboard
- Now when the person is redirected the home screen is showing the back button
- I have tried nav controller, tried to change the start destination id, but still nothing
  worked

Here are some  **codes**

*Defined in SelectLanguageFragment*

```
 private fun checkUserExist(){
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    val navOptions: NavOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
        .setPopUpTo(`in`.jadu.anjuconsumerapp.R.id.consumerHomeFragment, true)
        .build()
    if(currentUser != null){
        findNavController().navigate(`in`.jadu.anjuconsumerapp.R.id.action_selectLanguageFragment_to_consumerHomeFragment)
    }
}
```

Tried navOptions but didn't worked

Here is my `NavGraph`
[image: NavGraph]

**NavGraphCodes**

```
app:startDestination="@id/selectLanguageFragment"

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/selectLanguageFragment"
    android:name="in.jadu.anjuconsumerapp.consumer.commonuis.SelectLanguageFragment"
    android:label="Select Language" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_selectLanguageFragment_to_phoneVerificationFragment"
        app:destination="@id/phoneVerificationFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_selectLanguageFragment_to_consumerHomeFragment"
        app:destination="@id/consumerHomeFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/selectLanguageFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

I have tried `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` but i didn't need this i just want to remove it from the navigation,

###### I want to Remove this back button from the home screen when user is logged in

#### Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So after struggling a lot watched a lot many yt videos, github I finally got the solution from  **androidx Docs**  [Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#create_a_toolbar)

So, When we are setting up the navigate up ...

1. Only the `Top Level Ids` will not have the back arrow
2. So we need to define the dashboard fragment as a top level or start id (languagefragment is only the start previously)

**code**

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            topLevelDestinationIds = setOf(R.id.selectLanguage,R.id.farmerDashboard),
            fallbackOnNavigateUpListener = ::onSupportNavigateUp
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
```

Here i have declared both the fragments (selectLanguage,farmerDashboard) as top level so that i would not get the back button on these ids the rest app works fine ...

So , this was a simple thing

Hope this helps you :)